# How can I run a animation by the animation name generated on the cocos studio? (cocos2s-js)

Tags: cocos2d-js

It can create the animation name on the timeline at CocosStudio2.
But I don't know the way of calling it from cocos2d-js(v3.6).
How can I run a animation by the name?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you are looking for, but in the cocos 2d-js you can run an action or a sequence of actions (Animation), here is a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s46AtHxDRdM!